# kernel connection issues when using Jupyter Notebook extension (within VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter

It's been a little over a month since I'm using Jupyter notebooks, as an inbuilt extension within Visual Studio Code, and am pretty satisfied with it. However, recently I've been noticing that sometimes for no particular reason, I get a "direct kernel connection broken" error message when I attempt to run the specific cell upon which I'm working at that moment.

[image: The error message in action]

I do understand that this might be due to some errors that regularly creep up in my code, but something that I've noticed is that, say for instance that a particular snippet of the code that I've written is buggy. When I run the snippet in the traditional Jupyter Notebook (via my power shell, hosted as a web-based browser application) it shows the nature of the error, and where exactly has it occurred in the body of the program. For the VS Code based Jupyter Notebook extension, it does nothing of that sort and just displays a "Direct kernel connection broken" error message.

[image: Dashboard of Jupyter Notebook's Extension for VS Code]
I have tried everything - from interrupting the kernel by toggling the red square key to restarting the kernel with the help of the green 'reload' key, but nothing seems to change. Occasionally during this issue, If close and open VS Code, or start coding in a new blank notebook, then this small trick does seem to return the kernel state back to normal. Nevertheless, I'm growing increasingly tired of this temporary fixture and was hoping to fix this issue permanently.

Edit: For further clarification, I have added two pictures for comparison. Both the snapshots are of the same snippet of code. The first picture is of my code running on a traditional Jupyter Notebook ( and it seems to work fine ).
[image: Code Snippet running on a traditional Jupyter Notebook]

The second picture is a snapshot of the same code snippet, running on VS Code's Extension for Jupyter Notebook.
[image: Code Snippet running on Visual Studio Code's Extension for Jupyter Notebook]

For further information, kindly refer to the comments below.

Comment: Baneswar Can you provide a specific example and the related picture？Because I did not meet this kind of problem before.

Comment: @Steven Yes, surely. I have updated my question with a picture of a snippet of my code. The code in the cell ( which is infinitely running) is supposed to perform a multiplication recursively i.e It multiplies two given numbers and returns the result without using the multiplication arithmetic operator (*).  As you can see above, it works perfectly fine on the traditional Jupyter Notebook. However, it displays a "direct kernel connection broken" error message when I attempt to run it in the VS Code based extension of Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I'm a developer on this extension. Usually that message is seen if there is something that creates an out of memory issue. Not sure if that is the case here. If you could you could pull the contents of the Jupyter tab of the VS Code output window. That's where we have our logging, might be something that I can see in there.

Comment: @IanHuff Firstly, Thank you for bearing with me and looking into this issue. I have extracted the log contents and had tried to update my question with the same, but unfortunately, it exceeded the word limit. Is there any other way I can show the log contents?

Comment: @IanHuff https://controlc.com/e89c930c
 Here you go. This is the only log report generated, from what I could gather (not too sure if it's the correct one). Again, I'm not really sure whether this actually fits the description of the log that you asked for. So it would be great if you could kindly go through it once and give your valuable inputs if possible...

Comment: Yes, that's the log. I'm not seeing anything that stands out in there. Question, from the look it looks like you also have a different python installed on the system:

Info 2021-07-02 09:05:51: findPreferredKernel score for Python3, Python 3.8.8 64-bit ('base': conda) is 4

Could you try running that cell with that python selected instead of the 3.9 version? Just trying to rule something out.

Comment: @Ian Huff As of now, It feels that your suggestion was spot on, and there doesn't seem to be any better solution than that of yours. For the timing, it looks like switching the default kernel to "Python 3.8.8 64-bit ('base': conda)" does the trick and makes the errors appear more naturally, instead of letting them go past undetected. Additionally, it also significantly lessens the occurrence of a "direct kernel connection broken" error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! All of it was tremendously helpful!
 Do you have any theory as to why such a problem was happening? Also, how can I permanently set my default kernel to the "Python 3.8.8 64-bit ('base': conda)"one? (instead of always changing it from the drop-down menu)